# My APImage for Java isn't working?

Tags: java

The code for my entire class is:

```
package picturetest;
import images.APImage;

public class PictureTest{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        APImage image = new APImage("cat4.jpg"); //Line 12
        image.draw();

    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at images.APImage.setWindowAttributes(APImage.java:230)
    at images.APImage.<init>(APImage.java:86)
    at picturetest.PictureTest.main(PictureTest.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Where is your `cat4.jpg` located?

Comment: check if the path of the image file is correct or not ? or try giving absolute path.

Comment: `cat4.jpg` would need to be situated within the same directory for the executing JAR file. Try providing a full path first.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code for `APImage`...

Comment: The code for APImage is the same as seen on its website: http://home.wlu.edu/~lambertk/hsjava/edition4/whatsnew/imagedocs/images/APImage.html i downloaded it from that website. As for my cat image I just tried a full path and it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You can print the working directory with this code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Give the "cat4.jpg" path related to that.